# get the current location of mobile when device GPS is off. mobile web application

Tags: java, javascript, mobile-website

i am developing a mobile web application. i want  to detect the current location of the device even when the device GPS is Off. Is there any way we can do it? can  implementation methods like (cell/sector/triangulation) are possible to do it?

are there any api's which can help to do it?please help.

thanks and regards,
vinay

Answer (score 1):

2 options based on where you want to determine - 
Java Script side. This wraps the HTML5 spec - 
Google Geolocation API - http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/

Or you could determine it on the server based on the IP address of the mobile phone (rememeber to make it clear to your users that you are using the IP to determine the location)
http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/03/31/3-free-ways-to-geolocate-by-ip/

Comment: hi  thanks for the reply.  i need some clarification. 1) Will google GeoLocation API work even when device GPS is OFF? 2) are there separate api's to get the current location for the two cases ie: case1:  when device GPS is ON and case 2: when device GPS is OFF